# Benchmarking Mongodb Queries Without cache

Tags: performance, mongodb, mongodb-3.0, benchmark, mongodb-3.4, query-performance

I want to benchmark some Mongodb queries by calculating their execution time but I could not find a way to do so without caching : The first time I execute a query it takes a decent amount of time and the second time I execute the same query it is extremely faster which means it was due to caching.

I tried clearing linux cache :  echo 3 > /proc/sys/vm/drop_caches and also Mongodb plan cache clearing db..getPlanCache().clear() but it didn't solve the problem.

Are there any way to always measure a query execution duration as if it is executed for the first time ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Profiling](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/manage-the-database-profiler/) with level 2 stores needed information.

If you reboot mongod process and drop linux caches, it will empty all used caches.

Comment: The database is in production and a restart of mongod service is not possible in my case.

Comment: If your mongodb is replicaset, moving primary to node what has not been primary after last start of mongod process (on that node) will generate same result. During time when node is secondary, you can restart it's mongod process.